# How should I configure the wysiwyg filter to align the images?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

This is how my configuration in the wysiwyg filter looks like (in Drupal7):

```
a[!href|target<_blank|title],
img[src|align<bottom?left?middle?right?top|alt|border|class|height|width|float],
div[align<center?justify?left?right],
p[align<center?justify?left?right],
br,span,em,strong,cite,code,blockquote,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd
```

However my configuration does not work for aligning images.

I have reviewed my code and the alignment is done using the "style" tag:

```
<img src="" alt="" style="float:right" />
```

I tried the following configuration for the image but that does not work either:

```
img[src|align<bottom?left?middle?right?top|alt|border|class|height|width|float|**style**],
```

Here is another attempt that did not work:

```
@[style]
```

And I also tried like so:

```
img[*],
```

Another attempt is what is detailed in this alternative: http://screencast.com/t/jUOwMxmpu

So what is the right configuration for the images to be aligned? What is my error?

Comment: Maybe you still have Drupal's default "Limit allowed HTML tags" filter enabled, besides wysiwyg_filter? This filters out any inline css styles on display.

Answer (score 1):

Some people forget to turn off the built-in HTML Filter when they enable the WYSIWYG Filter.  If you double-filter, you will lose your img attributes.

For my part, though, I prefer to not put the `float` on the `img`; instead, I float the div that surrounds the image and caption, allowing them to float together.  (Example image, with floated caption "A battle...": http://www.westkingdom.org/content/new-members).  To give the content editors a good user experience, I allow them to set floats on images with ckeditor, but I move the markup to the div in a render hook when the content is displayed.  In this scenario, I don't need to allow floats on the image at all.

I have [a writeup of how I achieved responsive images with captions](http://www.wkweb.westkingdom.org/documentation/how-create-responsive-captioned-inline-images-using-drupal-media-module) using media 2.0, wysiwyg filter, and a couple other modules, and a couple of custom hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the style attribute on your image tag `img[!src|style]` and then you need to *also* whitelist the style properties that can be used. You should see a "Layout Properties" group of checkboxes, check the one that says "float."

Comment: I tried to configurate with your suggests:  http://screencast.com/t/WCupjASwmy44 and http://screencast.com/t/74iOevHtL9f and nothing.  Thanks for your help and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? I just tested the configuration on a clean install and it works.

Comment: I cleared cache and nothing.  The images on the editor are not alignment.